# JitCompilerFactory Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

How to use JitCompilerFactory in angular 5?

in angular 4 '@angular/compiler' exported JitCompilerFactory

but in angular 5 file moved to "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/compiler_factory"

this my code in Angular 4

```
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common'
import {Compiler, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {JitCompilerFactory} from '@angular/compiler'
import {DynamicComponent} from './dynamic.component'
import {DynamicComponentModule} from './dynamic.module'

export function compilerFactory() {
    return new JitCompilerFactory([{useDebug: false, useJit: true}]).createCompiler()
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        DynamicComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        DynamicComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        DynamicComponentModule,
        {provide: Compiler, useFactory: compilerFactory}
    ],
})
export class DynamicModule {
}
```

how to make this works in Angular 5?

Answer (score 4):

You must update `@angular/platform-browser-dynamic`to the very latest version (`5.1.0-beta.2`) and get the factory from :

```
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
```

> The third beta brings 10 bugfixes and one feature, namely:
>   platform-browser-dynamic: export JitCompilerFactory (#20478)
>   (d7a727c), closes #20125

- Github feature request : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20125
- Github discussion : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20154
- See more about the release : https://jaxenter.com/road-to-angular-5-133253.html

Then, you shouldn't create the compiler yourself, you need to let the injector do the work here :

```
import {Compiler, COMPILER_OPTIONS, CompilerFactory, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {JitCompilerFactory} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

export function createCompiler(compilerFactory: CompilerFactory) {
  return compilerFactory.createCompiler();
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    {provide: COMPILER_OPTIONS, useValue: {}, multi: true},
     {provide: CompilerFactory, useClass: JitCompilerFactory, deps: [COMPILER_OPTIONS]},
     {provide: Compiler, useFactory: createCompiler, deps: [CompilerFactory]}
   ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Sorry to tell you that, but apparently **this won't work yet because work is still in progress :**

Credit goes to those guys : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20639#issuecomment-347149868

It killed my weekend so I hope it helps :) Cheers !

Comment: yes i create that thread 20125 & 20639 on angular issues, this is work without build-optimizer false flag

Comment: Oh wow, and i thought my answer would be useful :) Thanks for opening theses issues, I had a lot of fun reading from people angry at Angular, it felt a bit less lonely. Anyway, I got it working last night using this approach.

Comment: Did you get it working with an AOT build?  It seems like the compiler is stripping the decorators off my dynamic modules/components.

Comment: FYI I'm using angular 5 with Ionic 3, I don't know if there are any particularities with ionic scripts (except that they didn't jump to AOT yet, JIT is still default), but it built fine using the command : `ionic build android --aot`.
But I think you should do the same with `angular-cli`, pass `--aot` and/or `--prod` flags to the `ng` command.